# Why do I get a 'missing DNA' error when trying to open projects?

Tags: blend-files

When I try and open recent projects to my computer I can't. It just comes up with a red flag at the bottom and says that it can't be opened and must have some missing DNA.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: did you check this?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66697/blender-report-error-during-loading-dna-block-missing